# JavaScript generated number is always the same

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a number that doesn't replace another already existed number in a json file (orders.json) but in my discord.js bot everytime the command which makes the number keeps making the same number 002 and even creates it again when it already exists replacing the data in the json file which makes alot of issues with me

```
const json = require('../../orders.json')
const keys = Object.keys(json).map(el => parseInt(el));
const nums = [];
let i = 1;

while (i < 999) {
  if (!keys.includes(i)) {
    nums.push(`${i}`.padStart(3, '0'));
  }

  i++;
}
orderID = nums[1]
```

the generated number is orderID and it's not supposed to replace the same one in the json file
for example the json file has data like this

```
{
    "002": "some data here"
}
```

now its supposed to create the number 003 since 002 already exists in the json file but it creates the same number replacing the data which causes alot of issues
this is used for a discord bot which writes "orders" by numbers which aren't supposed to do that

EDIT: using Richard's answer

```
json = 
{ "001": "Something"
, "002": { "message": "And more stuff" }
, "003": 42
, "Suddenly": "Okay"
}

const keys = Object.keys(json).map(el => parseInt(el));

console.log(keys);

const nums = [];
i = 1;
while (i < 999) {
  if (!keys.includes(i)) {
    nums.push(`${i}`.padStart(3, '0'));
  }

  i++;
}
orderID = nums[0]

console.log(orderID);
```

with that code the console shows:

```
1
2
3
NaN
004
```

now I simply replaced `json =  { "001": "Something" , "002": { "message": "And more stuff" } , "003": 42 , "Suddenly": "Okay" }` with `const json = require ('../../orders.json')` while the orders.json has this data

```
{
    "001": { 
         "some data here"
     }
}
```

it only logs "001" which already exists in the json

Comment: You'll probably want `parseInt(el, 10)` to make sure you're parsing things in the correct unit. Type `020` into a javascript console to see what I mean.

Comment: Please show the contents of `console.log(keys)` and `console.log(nums)`.

Comment: `console.log(keys)` logs an empty message and `console.log(nums)` logs numbers from 001 to 999

Answer (score 0):

The first unused number will be  `nums[0]`.  Maybe that is what you need to use as the next `orderID`.

```js
json = 
{ "001": "Something"
, "002": { "message": "And more stuff" }
, "003": 42
, "Suddenly": "Okay"
}

const keys = Object.keys(json).map(el => parseInt(el));

console.log(keys);

const nums = [];
i = 1;
while (i < 999) {
  if (!keys.includes(i)) {
    nums.push(`${i}`.padStart(3, '0'));
  }

  i++;
}
orderID = nums[0]

console.log(orderID);
```

Comment: thanks but still the same thing when using it just generates 001 even when 001 already exists in the json file

Comment: I edited my question to explain the issue